# Opencart Database tables missing

Tags: opencart

I keep getting this error when trying to add a product in OpenCart 1.5.6 - it only started happening recently and I'm trying to trace back anything which might have been installed or uninstalled.

This is the error I seem to be getting. I was wondering if someone might know what the table is related to? I can then uninstall and reinstall.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: Table 'DBName.shop_profile' doesn't exist<br />Error No: 1146<br />SELECT `p`.`profile_id`, `p`.`sort_order`, `pd`.`name` FROM `shop_profile` AS `p` JOIN `shop_profile_description` AS `pd` ON `pd`.`profile_id` = `p`.`profile_id` AND `pd`.`language_id` = 1 ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC ' in /system/database/mysqli.php:41 Stack trace: #0 /system/library/db.php(20): DBMySQLi->query('SELECT `p`.`pro...') #1 /admin/model/catalog/profile.php(34): DB->query('SELECT `p`.`pro...') #2 /admin/controller/catalog/product.php(868): ModelCatalogProfile->getProfiles() #3 /admin/controller/catalog/product.php(64): ControllerCatalogProduct->getForm() #4 [internal function]: ControllerCatalogProduct->insert() #5 /system/engine/front.php(42): in /system/database/mysqli.php on line 41
```

Comment: by default in OpenCart all tables has prefix `oc_ ` regarding this error you want retrieve data from  table `shop_profile`  in you request without prefix.  Seems there some extension you have installed... You should check your database to ensure you have this `shop_profile` table and file where from request are coming.

Comment: Hi - yes I've checked this and the table itself doesn't exist. I think the oc_ was not used for security purposes.

Comment: so you should reinstall this module maybe this can help, or find table of this module and install it manually. Or remove this module files from your OC installation.

Comment: Completely understand, but the problem I have here is locating which module needs reinstalling - google doesn't seem to bring up anything for the tables.

Comment: Download all your shop installation and use text crawler something like notepad++ and find which file contain `shop_profile`

Comment: I did this, it didnt find anything. It seems to be a mysqli problem?

The problem occurs when I try to insert a product or update a product.

Comment: You can ask for commercial support in opencart commercial forum. https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=88

Comment: Thankyou, I will try that :-)